# PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics not supported on .NET 3.5?

Tags: postsharp

It seems that PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics.dll is not available for .NET 3.5.

I'm unable to use logging on .NET 3.5. Switching to .NET 4.0 works fine; however I need to target .NET 3.5.

When on .NET 3.5 the logging smart tag is also not available.

Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostSharp Pattern Libraries are not supported on .NET 3.5.

On the other hand PostSharp Aspect Framework (core of PostSharp) and PostSharp Architecture Framework are supported.

Comment: Thanks. You should be more clear about those limitations on your website. Saying that you support .NET 3.5 usually means that all of the features should be supported.

Comment: @IlyaSuzdalnitski See this page: https://www.postsharp.net/integration/platforms or this page http://doc.postsharp.net/requirements Is there any other place where the website is not correct? Thanks!